# SQL server: Split string with ',' delimiter

Tags: sql-server, split

I have an attribute that contrains names delimited with ',' like `"Sylvain GASNIER,Mickaël BENOIST,ect...,"` I would like to have in result

```
Sylvain GASNIER
Michaël BENOIST
..
..
```

The idea  is to test if a name exists in the first string, so I split the names then check.

this how I did but I get just the first name.

```
select 
       substring(TITULAIRE,1,CHARINDEX(',',TITULAIRE)-1 )
from dbo.DATA_ACTIONS
WHERE TITULAIRE LIKE 'Sylvain GASNIER,Mickaël BENOIST' and CHARINDEX(',',TITULAIRE) > 0;
```

I would like to do it in a procedure

Comment: are you banned in google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x

Comment: not banned but I don't find one easy to undestand

Comment: I would recommend reading Aaron Bertrand's answer instead of the accepted answer in the duplicate question. Using loops to split strings is horribly inefficient.